# Blog and comment issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, blogs

Currently I am having a problem regarding a blogging system.Where users will post their blogs and other members can comment on it. When the user will open his own home page he/she can see the blogs written by him/her with comments attached with each blog.like this-

**Blog 1**
.Comment1
.comment2
...

**Blog 2**
.Comment1
.comment2
.Comment3
....

and so on.I have two tables regarding this

1. `blog_tbl(blg_id,blg_title,blg_content,author_id,crt_date)`
2. `comments_tbl(cmmnt_id,blg_id,cmnt_txt,author_id,crt_date)`

Now I am able to display all the blogs. But facing problems when displaying the comments respective to a particular blog.
To fetch the comments these are my steps-

- I have got an array `$blog_ids` which contains latest 5 blogs' id.
- passing `$blog_ids` to my model

Code:

```
public function get_comments($blog_ids) {
    foreach($blog_ids as $row) {
        $blg_post_id = $row['blg_id'];
        $this->db->where('post_id', $blg_post_id);
        $get_comments = $this->db->get('comment_tbl');
        $cmnts = $get_comments->result_array();     
    }

    return $cmnts;          
}
```

- now I am passing this **$cmnts** array of result arrays to my view.
- In the view here I am not able to discriminate comments with respect to posts

first of all `$comnts` holds all comments mixed up for every blogs.How to discriminate.Secondly, in foreach loop I am doing something wrong, I is not displaying anything.Is it because its a array of arrays?

```
<ul class="cmmnt">
    <?php foreach($comnts as  $value){ ?>
        <li>
            <div class=cmnt_container>
                <div class=commnt_txt>
                    <span class="h5"><?php echo $value['comment_txt'] ;?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: you are always overwriting the comments array instead you have to append it

Answer (score 0):

You are putting all comments in the same variable **$cmnts**. You can try this:

```
    public function get_comments($blog_ids) 
    {
      foreach($blog_ids as $row)
      {
        // First declare $cmnts as array
        $cmnts = array();
        $blg_post_id = $row['blg_id'];

        $this->db->where('post_id', $blg_post_id);
        $get_comments = $this->db->get('comment_tbl');
        // You create separate array for each blog
        $cmnts['blg_id'] = $get_comments->result_array();
      }// Now you have array of comments  
        return $cmnts;          
     }// end of get_comments
```

**And when you need to connect comment with blog you do this:**

```
<ul class="cmmnt">
   <?php foreach($comnts as  $value)
     { 
    if($value['blg_id'] == $blg['blg_id']):
   ?>
<li>
  <div class=cmnt_container>
   <div class=commnt_txt>
     <span class="h5">
      <?php echo $value['comment_txt'] ;?>
     </span>
   </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
</ul>
```

Or you can try this (I don't know how are you displaying your blogs):

```
<ul class="cmmnt">
    <?php foreach($comnts[$blg_id] as  $value){?>
     <li>
      <div class=cmnt_container>
       <div class=commnt_txt>
        <span class="h5"><?php echo $value['comment_txt'] ;?>
        </span>
       </div>
     </div>
</ul>
```

**$blg['blg_id']** is the id of your blog.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpfull

```
public function get_comments($blog_ids) 
{
    foreach($blog_ids as $row)
    {

        $blg_post_id = $row['blg_id'];
        $this->db->where('post_id', $blg_post_id);
        $get_comments = $this->db->get('comment_tbl');
        $cmnts[] = $get_comments->result_array();//append the comments

    }
    return $cmnts;          
}
// end of get_comments
```

Please change your view like below

```
<ul class="cmmnt">
<?php 
     foreach($comnts as  $value)
     {
    foreach($value as  $value1)
    { ?>
    <li>
    <div class=cmnt_container>
    <div class=commnt_txt>
    <span class="h5"><?php echo $value1['comment_txt'] ;?></span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <?php 
       } 
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. in this context I want to ask you something I am using a little different approach.
$param = $posts['cnv_post_id']; //$posts['cnv_post_id']holds the current post id
$comments = $this->post_model->get_comments($param);

in model
public function get_comments($cnv_post_id) 
 { 
   
   $get_comments= $this->db->query('select * from cnv_comment where blog_tbl='.$cnv_post_id.'');
   if($get_comments->num_rows > 0) return $get_comments->result_array();
return array();   
}
 but its not giving the results. but if I explicitly give $param = '100' its returning the results.

Comment: sorry i'm not getting what you are trying

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311037/database-record-fetch-issue-in-codeigniter

please visit this link