# database record fetch issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using a the following approach.

```
$param = $posts['cnv_post_id']; //$posts['cnv_post_id']holds the current post id 
$comments = $this->post_model->get_comments($param);
```

in model :-

```
public function get_comments($cnv_post_id) 
{
  $get_comments = 
           $this->db->query('select * from cnv_comment where blog_tbl='.$cnv_post_id.'');
   if($get_comments->num_rows > 0) 
   return $get_comments->result_array(); 

}
```

but its not giving the results. but if I explicitly give $param = '100' where 100 is the current post id. now,  its returning the results

Comment: have you tried to run query it in phpmyadmin ? is it giving result ?

Comment: Your quoting in your query is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get the post from a form:

```
$param = $this->input->post('cnv_post_id');
```

---

Try outputing `$this->db->last_query()` and give it to us

Comment: Sorry, it will sound funny but I am doing this on my view within php tag

Comment: so what is `posts['cnv_post_id']`? How do you get it?

Comment: see post is an array passed to a view posts[] has other data to show.
I am just trying to fetch comment for every post.But is fetching null

Answer (score 0):

You try it.

```
$param = $this->input->post('cnv_post_id'); //$posts['cnv_post_id']holds the current post id 
$comments = $this->post_model->get_comments($param);

public function get_comments($cnv_post_id) 
{
  $get_comments = 
           $this->db->query("select * from cnv_comment where blog_tbl = '$cnv_post_id'");
   if($get_comments->num_rows() > 0) 
      return $get_comments->result_array(); 

}
```